# Build Failure ERROR: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (report)

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Trying to build project artifact with command "mvn clean install -U. It downloads for a long time but results in this build failure:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (report) on project MYPROJECT: Execution report of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.1.2184/sonar-maven-plugin-3.9.1.2184.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.2.588/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.2.588.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: The given plugin version needs at minimum JDK11 (`has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)` ) but you are building your project only with JDK8 (`this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`)... Why do you use `mvn install` and `-U` for sonarQube analysis.. not needed...only `mvn clean verify` is necessary..

Comment: updating to JDK11 from JDK8 did not fix this error

Comment: There are other issues which I can't even guess if an updated does not help here.. Which Maven version are you using?