# An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClass

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-2, maven-3, sonarqube-scan

I'm getting this error when trying to build the project artifact with command "mvn clean install -U":

> An API incompatibility was encountered while executing
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar:
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled
> by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
> 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Anyone know how to fix this? I have to use the command "mvn clean install -U"

Comment: Isn't that the same question as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75816025/296328

Comment: Why do you need to use `install -U` only `mvn verify` is needed if configured correctly...What does `mvn --version` tells you?

Comment: mvn --version gives me Apache Maven 3.9.0, java version 1.8.0_322

Comment: with mvn verify i got the same error in the original question. do you know if I need to add anything to my settings.xml file?

Comment: The issue here is that you need to use JDK11 (class file version 55.0) and not JDK 8 ..otherwise you can not use this plugin version....